# Java type compatibility between generics with nested template types

Tags: java, generics, nested-generics

```
List<Object> a = null;
List<?> b = null;
b = a; // Can be assigned

List<List<Object>> a = null;
List<List<?>> b = null;
b = a; // Cannot be assigned
```

Could you explain why Java does not allow the second case?
What are the side-effects of the case and underlying philosophy?

I have seen [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why are Java generics not implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265) but this question is different because there is the inheritance relationship between `Dog` and `Animal` but here is **no** relationship between the wildcard type `?` and `Object`. Wildcard type represents 'some unknown type,' which means `List<?>` can be `List<Object>` in the runtime: Intuitively speaking, here `List<?>` is a candidate `Dog` (**Not `Animal`**), there `List<Object>` is a `Dog`.

`List<String>` cannot be assigned to `List<Object>`, which is the same case of the previous question and explained there why it is not allowed. However, `List<String>` can be assigned to `List<?>`, which is the case I am asking and different from the previous case. Since the assignment is allowed, I expected `List<List<Object>>` can be assigned to `List<List<?>>`.

Comment: See the duplicate. `List<Object>` is the `Dog` here, and `List<?>` is the `Animal`. You probably want to use `List<? extends List<?>>` as the type of `b`.

Comment: Suppose you did `b.add(0, new ArrayList<Integer>())` and then `a.get(0).add("uh oh")`. Now you have heap pollution.

Comment: @Sweeper `List<?>` can be any `List`, which means `List<?>` can be `List<Object>`. Is this same problem? I am not sure about that. I think wildcard should be treated differently. Am I wrong? please let me know..

Comment: `Animal` can be any subclass of `Animal`, which can be `Dog`. The subtyping relationships are basically the same.

Comment: @Sweeper Can you let me know which type can be assigned to variable `b` in the example? Based on your explanation, I think there is no type that can be assigned to `b` except itself. Am I right?

Comment: Well the type argument has to be `List<?>`, but you can do `ArrayList<List<*>>` for example.

Comment: @Sweeper `List<List<?>> b = new ArrayList<>(); List<Object> c = new ArrayList<>(); List<String> d = new ArrayList<>(); b.add(c); b.add(d);` works but `b = a` does not work, which confuses me a lot. Although after I define `List<List<? extends Object>> b`, `c` and `d` still can be added to `b` but not `b=a`. Hmm.... I have to think about it more... thank you for your answers

Comment: See @Sweeper 's first comment: `List<Object>` is the `Dog` and `List<?>` is the `Animal`. `Dog` can be assigned to `Animal`, but that doesn't mean that a `List<Dog>` can be assigned to  a `List<Animal>`. A `List<List<Object>>` can't be assigned to a `List<List<?>>` for exactly the same reason.